# How do I insert a user input that incl spaces from an HTML form into a declarativeNetRequest dynamic rule and encode those spaces as "%20" and not "+"

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, urlencode

I am building an extension that allows users to replace UTM parameters with their own strings. I want to support strings that have spaces in between words. So, for example, a user input of `test input` creates a dynamic rule through the declarativeNetRequest feature for the URL `google.com/?utm_source=originalsource` to redirect to the result `google.com/?utm_source=test%20input`

The `%20` part is where I am running into problems, as no matter what I try, I cannot get an output that gives `%20` for `<space>`. I think this is because at some point after I transform the URL, the browser re-encodes it, giving me an output of %2520, which is just the encoding for `%` (`%25`) appended to the following `20`. If I don't do anything to the input and just take it as a value `<space>` appears as `+`.

**My question is: how can I take a user input with spaces in it, use that input to create a dynamic rule, and make sure that the end URL the browser directs to after processing the rule encodes those spaces as `%20`.**

Here is the popup.js that triggers the rule, I've made each replacement follow slightly different logic and commented the output each rule gives.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentEvents, false);

function myAction(input) { 
    console.log("input value is : " + input.value);
    alert("The entered data is : " + input.value);
}

function documentEvents() {    
  document.getElementById('ok_btn').addEventListener('click', 
    function() {
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
          removeRuleIds: [1],
          addRules: [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "action": {
              "type": "redirect",
              "redirect": {
                "transform": {
                  "queryTransform": {
                    "addOrReplaceParams": [
                      //dont use any input, just manually replace utm_source with the static value "test%20input", outputs "test%2520input"
                      {"key": "utm_source", "value": "test%20input"},
                      //get the input from the textbox and turn it into a string, for input "test input" outputs "test+input"
                      {"key": "utm_medium", "value": document.getElementById('name_textbox').value},
                      //get the input get the input from the textbox and turn it into a string, 
                      //then encode it as a URI component, for input "test input" outputs "test%2520input"
                      {"key": "utm_term", "value": encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value)},
                      //get the input get the input from the textbox and turn it into a string,
                      //then encode it as a URI component and replace " " with "%20", for input "test input" outputs "test%2520input"
                      {"key": "utm_content", "value": encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value).replace(" ", "%20")},
                      //get the input get the input from the textbox and turn it into a string,
                      //then encode it as a URI component and replace " " with "\%20", I thought the escape might help, for input "test input" outputs "test%2520input"
                      {"key": "utm_campaign", "value": encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value).replace(" ", "\%20")}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          "condition": {
          "regexFilter": "[?&]utm_(source|medium|term|content)=[^&]+",
          "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
        }
        }
        ]
  });
        console.log("input value is : " + document.getElementById('name_textbox').value);
        console.log("input value with space replaced by %20 : " + document.getElementById('name_textbox').value.replace(" ", "%20"));
        console.log("input value is with encodeURIComponent : " + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value));
        console.log("input value is with encodeURIComponent and space replaced by 20 : " + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value.replace(" ", "%20")));  
})
}
```

Currently, for the user input `test input` and the URL `https://about.fb.com/regulations/?utm_source=fillersource&utm_medium=fillermedium&utm_term=fillerterm&utm_content=fillercontent&utm_campaign=fillercampaign`, this above logic directs users to `https://about.fb.com/regulations/?utm_source=test%2520input&utm_medium=test+input&utm_term=test%2520input&utm_content=test%2520input&utm_campaign=test%2520input`

here's the manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "CustomUTMPopup",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Custom UTM testing",
  "action": {
  "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"],
    "icons": {
          "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```

and the popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UTM Replacer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>     
  </head>
  <body>   

    <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">           
        <h3>Hello,</h3>
        <p>Please write your UTM replacement: </p>         
        <input id="name_textbox" />                   
         <button id="ok_btn" type="button">OK</button>
    </div>      

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `.replace(/ /g, "%20")`. Also I see you've used my answer so please mark it as a solution.

Comment: Done! Also this solution still runs into the problems above where the `%20` still gets encoded as `%2520`. Any idea how to avoid this? I think the problem is somewhere between the URL transformation in the function and the URL encoding by chrome. Including your solution, all of these functions log test%20input in my console log at the end (with the exception of `"encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name_textbox').value.replace(" ", "%20"))` which logs %2520.)

Comment: encodeURIComponent(foo).replace(/\+/g, "%20")

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can do it because declarativeNetRequest encodes your value internally anyway. Just leave it as `+` and there should be no problem.

Comment: Cool, I am doing some testing to see if I need it to be `%20` specifically, but you're right in that `+` may be sufficient. Will update here. Also you've been super helpful this entire time, lmk if there's a project I can donate to or something to show my thanks :)